# global 'wait' is not callable (a nil value)

Tags: lua

**im newbie**, and i cannot understand simple problem at my opinion,
my code is pretty simple and short, because i just trying to understand how's lua working.

```
i = 1
repeat
    i = i + 1
    print (i)
    wait(0.5)
until i == 2000
print ("variable i, got value 2000, code has been stopped.")
```

the error is: **global 'wait' is not callable (a nil value)**

and i just cannot understand, how i need to call lua function "wait"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain the error message, any name that is not a local variable is considered global. All global variables are `nil`, unless we assign some other value to them. `nil` can't be called like a function can.

Unfortunately, there is no `wait` function in Lua's standard library. You can try to find something on luarocks.org that has it. If I understand what you're trying to do, the function you want is usually called `sleep`.

[Luarocks search](https://luarocks.org/search?q=sleep)

Comment: Now it works how i wanted
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is the Luarocks wait/sleep CPU friendly? - Or sounds your CPU Fan like a jet propulsion when waiting 60s with it in Lua?

Comment: @koyaanisqatsi: I don't know about Luarocks, but I've [implemented a `sleep` function](https://github.com/luther9/intervalbeep-lua/blob/master/sleep.cpp) that just calls the C `sleep`. It does not run the CPU while sleeping. I guess it just uses a system call to temporarily stop the process. It's very likely that the ones on Luarocks do the same thing.

Comment: Ah. OK - I see. Thats C# Code? I like to test it but i have no clue how to compile it. Can you give me a hint? By myself i use a precompiled C library ```wait.so``` and import/load ```wait()``` for example with: ```package.loadlib('/home/knoppix/lua/wait.so','wait')()```

Comment: @koyaanisqatsi: No, it's C++. `git clone` the repo, go to the directory, and type `scons`. Do some googling if you need to install dependencies.